# testing authorization access in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I had this simple test my mvc4 application using nunit and moq

```
[Test]
void IndexAction_ReturnsIndexView()
{
    // arrange
    string expected = "Index";
    var mock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    UserController controller = new UserController(mock.Object);

    // act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.ViewName);

    Assert.Fail("Incomplete test method");
}
```

I'm wonder how can I test following situation
User `john` belongs to `SuperUser` role and User `marice` belongs to `Editor` role.

How can I test response if marice tries to access to superuser pages?

Comment: You should create a provider that you can use to determine user permissions and memberships.  You can then create a unit test around that.  When testing controller results, you would need to mock your provider and inject it into the controller as a part of the controllercontext, as an HttpContextBase, if decisions are made in the controller method based on a user's role.